# Prove for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ , S.T the numbers $p-1,p+1,p+2$ have $n$ different prime factors .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Prove for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are infinitely many primes $p$  , S.T the numbers $p-1,p+1,p+2$ have $n$ different prime factors .

***Attempt***:

by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic's

we know that
$$p-1=p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_n}$$
also $$p+1=q_1^{a_1}...q_k^{a_n}$$
$$p+2=w_1^{a_1}...w_k^{a_n}$$

Noticing that all the factorizations consists of $n$ different prime factors.

1. I tried proving a stronger case with adding $p$ and its factorization to achieve 4 consecutive numbers. However that led me no where.
2. I tried to solve it with the Chinese remainder theorem using the abstract idea that there is only one unique $x_0$ solution. Not sure how to continue with this idea.

Comment: Couldn't you use the fact that if $gcd(a,b)=1$ there are infinitely many primes of the form $an+b$?

Comment: Do you mean "at least $n$"?  If $n=1$, your post would appear to require $4$ consecutive primes.

Comment: $(p-1,p+1)\ge2$ if p is odd.

Comment: If the claim is "exactly" $n$ then it is false, as the case $n=1$ shows.

Comment: What exactly is the claim.  That $p-1,p+1,p+2$ have exactly $n$ factors each?  That the total number of factors for then $3$ are $n$?

Comment: @lulu Correction ,  the claim holds for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I strongly doubt that you can prove the claim about "exactly $n$" factors for any $n$.

Comment: And, please edit your post to clearly  indicate the question you mean to ask. As it stands, you clearly specify "for all $n$"  and you are not clear as to whether you mean "at least $n$" or "exactly $n$."

Comment: Done , thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments:
If the question is asking for exactly $n$ factors, then the claim is false for every $n$, for the following simple reason:

If $p \neq 2,$ then $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2},$ thus $p-1$ and $p+1$ are both divisible by $2$, thus can not have different prime factorizations.

However, the statement is true for *at least* $n$ different prime factors:

Let $p_1,...,p_n, q_1,...,q_n, r_1,...,r_n$ be different odd prime numbers.

Let $P = p_1p_2 \cdots p_n, Q =q_1q_2\cdots q_n$ and $ R= r_1r_2\cdots r_n.$

(1) By the  Chinese Remainder Theorem,
\begin{align*} 
x-1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{P} \\
x+1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{Q}\\
x+2 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{R} \\
\end{align*}
has a solution.

(2) Let $x\in \mathbb{N}$ be a solution of the congruence equations. Note that  $x_k = x+ k \cdot PQR $ is also a solution for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

(3) Now $(x,PQR) =1$, so by Dirichlet's theorem of primes in arithemetic progression you get the result.

Comment: To stress:  this argument makes sense *if* the question is asking for "at least $n$" distinct prime factors.  The OP, however, has insisted on "exactly $n$" distinct prime factors (for which the claim is certainly false, at least for $n=1$).

Comment: @lulu I am pretty sure the question asking for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Great answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: @asemabdelraouf line (3) why $\gcd(x,PQR)=1$ ?? can you explain please ?

Comment: Assume $p_1 | x, $ then $x = s p_1$ for some $s$. But using the congruence,  $ x= 1 + t P$ for some $t,$ thus $ 1 = p_i ( s- t \frac{P}{p_i}),$ which is a contradiction. (Becuase $s- t \frac{P}{p_i}$ is an integer). You can do the same for all the primes dividing $PQR.$